# How would I create a "wall" on the left and right side of my screen Swift Spritekit?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want objects to be able to pass through the bottom and top of the screen but not be able to leave the right and left side. I have this code but when my objects go to the left or right it doesn't act as a wall and lets it go right through it. I used the contactTestBitMask to make sure there was contact but there is no collision. This is the code for the wall on the left:

```
func wall() {
    let leftWall = SKNode()
    leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(1.0, 
    1.0, 1.0, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)));
    leftWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = OutsideCategory
    leftWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    leftWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    leftWall.physicsBody?.mass = 5
    leftWall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    leftWall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    leftWall.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    leftWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    leftWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    leftWall.position = CGPointMake(0, self.size.height / 40)
    leftWall.setScale(1.0)
    self.addChild(leftWall)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the category bit mask is set on your wall, and your walls do in fact exist where you expect them to exist (you can set a flag on the scene to draw physics bodies which will display your wall), and the collisionBitMask of the nodes that should collide with the walls are set to the categoryBitMask of the wall (and you have created world physics body on the scene), you should be good to go.

Example:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
    _catNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryBlock | CNPhysicsCategoryEdge | CNPhysicsCategorySpring;

_catNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryBed | CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
```

The cat sprite node in this example will collide with the world physics body now.

Your collisionBitMask cannot be set to 0. It must match an enum value that coinsides with the categoryBitMask of the other objects. Per apple's documentation:

> `collisionBitMask`  Property A mask that defines which categories of
>   physics bodies can collide with this physics body.

**Declaration** 
SWIFT `var collisionBitMask: UInt32 OBJECTIVE-C`

> `@property(nonatomic, assign) uint32_t collisionBitMask`

**Discussion** When

> two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur. This
>   body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by
>   performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero value,
>   this body is affected by the collision. Each body independently
>   chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other body. For
>   example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations that would
>   make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.
>
> The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).

Example:

```
CGRect bodyRect = CGRectInset(frame, 2, 2);
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bodyRect.size];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryBlock;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryBlock | CNPhysicsCategoryCat | CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
```

Comment: I already see my walls when I set the showPhysics to true. I see it on the edge of the left side its just not having any collision. How would I set a flag on the scene?. I have been working on this for a couple of days and cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: If you set everything up like the above and didn't configure an odd flag like dynamic = true or resting = true on the sprite node, then you should be good to go.

Comment: Im still not getting any collision for some reason.

Comment: There must be some odd configuration on the sprite node then. Check the physics bodies of the sprite node and ensure that everything is configured to use physics rather manual calculations. By the sounds of it, if you're getting a collision callback and you've set the collisionBitMasks correctly, then there's a flag telling it not to react to the collision.

Comment: Does it matter the width of the node? Because the scale is only set to 1.0.

Comment: Well, if the node is extremely small you may want to turn on the high precision flag

Comment: I did that its still going right through the wall. I want to make sure your understanding me and I want something like this but in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491187/spritekit-create-a-wall

Comment: Yeah I understand, i still think you are either missing one of the configurations above or have set another flag. There are multiple way to do what your asking but you should always have a box surrounding the scene if thing are falling and not removed. You can clamp values for the y axis on objects that move, you can make a box with a larger height than width, etc.

Comment: The simple fact that you get a collision callback is proof enough collision is working. There are just no forces applied to the object at collision.

Comment: I don't know the collision setup of the object your expecting to collide with the wall. I just see your collisionBitMask is set to 0 rather an ENUM value. you need to ensure whatever object is colliding with the left wall has a categoryBitMask that matches the collisionBitMask of the leftWall.

Comment: Per apple's docs for collisionBitMask: When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur. This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero value, this body is affected by the collision. Each body independently chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other body. For example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations that would make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.

Comment: It works when i make a rectangle with 50 width but it sticks out and I can't position it the way I want.

Comment: Get your code working with this first:     self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryEdge; after that try to move forward with what you have

Comment: Also reflect on the stuff I put above. The apple docs specifically say: If the result is a nonzero value, this body is affected by the collision. In your case above, it will always be zero meaning no collision will affect the body.

Comment: I don't have access toy Mac right now but I'll try it tommorow. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll look through the posts again.

Comment: When you do self.frame isn't it going to cover up the entire screen?

Comment: It's an edge rect, this will setup a boundary around the full screen. It doesn't cover the full screen, just draws a boundary around it. This is simply to help you debug your collisions. Once you setup it up correctly with you should be able to set the same configuration to your wall sprites and remove the edge boundary.

Comment: So I could set it up on the left and right side and remove the top and bottom?